# HTTP response code for request that is too complicated or difficult to compute

Tags: http, httpresponse, http-response-codes

Say I have a server that calculates factorials:

```
> GET localhost:8080/factorial/10

200 3628800
```

In my analytics 99% of my users ask for factorials that are computationally cheap to calculate, but most of my CPU time goes towards the 1% of users that want to know `factorial(100+)`.

Now, I know how to calculate `factorial(100)`, I just *don't want to*, so I'm not going to fulfill these requests. What HTTP code should I respond with?

Note: `factorial` is just an example - in reality there is no hard and fast way for me to determine ahead of time which request will be too expensive and which won't, I have to decide on a case-by-case basis for each request and some will get an HTTP 200 back with their result, and others will get rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that if your *server* doesn't want to respond to such a request and its *not* the client's fault then perhaps a 5xx error makes sense? Maybe a [501 based on wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors) makes sense?

I would return a 500 with an error message to indicate the server's intention to explicitly not respond to such requests, but that's me.

Comment: I think this might be right. When looking at 5xx errors my first thought was, "but it's not an error!" Wikipedia says about these errors, "The server failed to fulfill a request". These all seem to indicate that something wrong and unexpected happened and a bug needs fixing. The don't quite capture the, "No, Thank You" response I'm looking for, but may still be the closest fit.

Comment: Yeah. I hear you. My only other thought was a 422 but the client didn’t technically ask for anything incorrectly. I really don’t think the codes cover this case which is why is lean towards an error message